# How to play a song from particular point?

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm preparing an audio player in swift ,in which I want to start the audio from  a particular point of the song.Any suggestions?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1389324-play ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AVAudioPlayer you can easily seek to required audio position by assigning TimeInterval value to currentTime property:

```
func seek(to time: TimeInterval) {
    let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: filePath)
    player.currentTime = time
}
```